# Switch and Character

Tags: switch-statement, character

with the following code

```
switch(taxband)
    {
        case 'A':
            str2="0-100";
        case 'B':
            str2="101-110";
        case 'C':
            str2="111-120";
        case 'D':
            str2="121-130";
        case 'E':
            str2="131-140";
        case 'F':
            str2="141-150";
        case 'G':
            str2="151-160";    
        default:
            str2="";
    }
```

str2 always takes the default value, even if taxband is equals to A or other letter.

Why ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out if the correct case is found. Otherwise the default case will always be evaluated.

```
switch(taxband)
{
    case 'A':
        str2="0-100";
        break;
    case 'B':
        str2="101-110";
        break;
    case 'C':
        str2="111-120";
        break;
    case 'D':
        str2="121-130";
        break;
    case 'E':
        str2="131-140";
        break;
    case 'F':
        str2="141-150";
        break;
    case 'G':
        str2="151-160";
        break;
    default:
        str2="";
}
```